# How can I do addition repetition in PHP

Tags: php

For example, I have a small function that I want it to keep adding to it its results .

```
$test1 = 1;
$test2 = 2;
$doitanumbeoftime = 6;

$results = $test1 + $test2;

echo $results; //// which it will print out 3.
```

now my question, after the `$results` was found, I want that results to be added to `$test2` variable and find that results and add it to `$test2` one more time and so on till it did it 6 times.

So, I need a function/ loop that can illustrate this results.

so for the first results, it should be 3. 
second results should be  5.
3rd results should be 7
4th results should be 9
5th results should be 11
and the 6th results should be 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this creates the output you ask for (3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13):

```
$test1 = 1;
$test2 = 2;
$doitanumbeoftime = 6;

$result = $test1;
for ($i=0;$i<$doitanumbeoftime;$i++){
    $result = $result + $test2;
    echo $result . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly and it was clear and understandable. it did give the results I was looking for. thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
$test1 = 1;
$test2 = 2;
$times = 6;

for($i = 1; $i <= $times; $i++) {
    echo $test1 + $test2 * $i . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: @positiv: Done! Now what would you like me to do?

Comment: @positiv: No! I didn't. Did you? I'm fairly confident it's right. But if you don't trust me, I will run it. http://codepad.org/GqME7OiE. Works nicely.

Comment: crikey. i really need to read the question 3 - 4 times before it actually sinks in. old age is catching up. glad i don't have to take exams any more, i would be royally screwed. *thumbs up*

Comment: Ok, I just tested with numbers I'm working on and it's giving me mess up results. my numbers were $test1=123.9 and $test2=.20...  and that function doesn't really do the addition, .. the correct results should be 123.9  124.09  
124.1  
124.5  
124.7  
124.9  
125.1 
125.3   
125.5

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $doitnumberoftimes; $i++) {
    $results = $test1 + $test2;
    $test2 += results;
    echo $results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$test1 = 1;
$test2 = 2;
$doitanumbeoftime = 6;

$results = $test1 + $test2;

for($i = 1; $i < $doitanumbeoftime; $i++)
$results += $test2;

echo $results;  // 13
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this one too

Comment: I would vote it up, but I'm new at the forum and it says I need 15 reputation.